# Splitting columns

Tags: r, split, delimiter

I have a column called Name which has entries as shown in the image below

[image: Name Column]

so the first entry is the make of the car, then model and then variant. The problem is that not all entries follow the same pattern.

e.g. Suzuki Wagon R VXL

Make - Suzuki

Model - Wagon R

Variant - VXL

So when I split it according to this

```
new_data_split = new_working %>% separate(Name, c("Make","Model","Variant"), sep = "\\ ", 
                                       remove = FALSE, fill = "right")
```

the column variant will have R in it except for VXL

Comment: Can you add the data in the question with ```dput()```, instead of posting an Image?

Comment: `The problem is that not all entries follow the same pattern.` ... you really need to show us all varieties in the input data.  Otherwise, any answer would have to make assumptions about what your data is.

Comment: sample = dput(new_data_split[1:20,])

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a vector of model and manufacturer names. Then you can extract them from the Name and use the remaining text as the variant:

```r
library(tidyverse)

manufacturers <- c("Suzuki", "Toyota")
models <- c("Wagon", "Make", "Corolla")

tibble(Name = c("Suzuki Wagon R VXL", "Make - Suzuki", "Toyota Corolla XLi VWTi 2010")) %>%
  transmute(
    manufacturer = Name %>% str_extract(manufacturers %>% paste0(collapse = "|")),
    model = Name %>% str_extract(models %>% paste0(collapse = "|")),
    # everything else
    variant = Name %>% str_remove_all(manufacturer) %>% str_remove_all(models) %>% str_trim()
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   manufacturer model   variant      
#>   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>        
#> 1 Suzuki       Wagon   R VXL        
#> 2 Suzuki       Make    -            
#> 3 Toyota       Corolla XLi VWTi 2010
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: that could work but the variants are usually contains letters only and not the years at the end.

Comment: You can add a `str_remove_all("[0-9]+")` for example to remove the numbers. Another way is just to make a list of variants as well.